# Write and edit text in Windows (particularly Visual Studio) using a stylus

Tags: windows, visual-studio, stylus-pen

Is there any hardware or software that would let me edit text documents and simulate mouse clicks using just a stylus? I want to be able to write programs in Visual Studio using a stylus for keyboard and mouse input. Hardware cost isn't an issue. Thanks.

P.S. I have an wrist RSI that is making typing on a keyboard impossible but I really don't want to end my programming career. I know there are other input methods but this is the one I'd most prefer.

Answer (score 2):

There was a Tablet PC edition of Windows XP that offered stylus support, including handwriting recognition.  Since then, tablet functions and handwriting OCR have been baked straight into Windows.

If you're running Vista, 7, 8 or 8.1, you can probably launch it right now.  Search for the Tablet PC folder in the Start Menu.  In Windows 7, you'll find it under Accessories.

As far as using handwriting OCR in VS is concerned: I would expect you'll need to tune your dictionary to include the names of components, or turn off predictive corrections entirely.  Camelcase and autocorrect don't see eye to eye.